# Update a calculation of a field when a dataframe is refreshed - Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
d = {'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
     'm1': ['2019-12-06', '2019-12-07','2019-12-07', '2019-12-06', '2020-12-09'], 
     'm2': ['2019-12-07', None, None, '2019-12-07', None], 
     'm3': [None, None, None, '2019-12-09', None],
     'm1_m2': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
     'm2_m3': [3, 3, 4, 1, 2]}

dat = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

print(dat)

```
   ID          m1          m2          m3  m1_m2  m2_m3
0   0  2019-12-06  2019-12-07        None      1      3
1   1  2019-12-07        None        None      1      3
2   2  2019-12-07        None        None      2      4
3   3  2019-12-06  2019-12-07  2019-12-09      2      1
4   4  2020-12-09        None        None      3      2
```

I want to create 2 new fields fields that estimates m2 and m3.

m2_estimated and m3_estimated will be calculated everytime i dont have m2 and m3

The expected output is:

```
ID          m1          m2          m3     m1_m2    m2_m3   m2_estimated    m3_estimated
0   2019-12-06  2019-12-07        None         1        3           None      2019-12-10
1   2019-12-07        None        None         1        3     2019-12-08      2019-12-11
2   2019-12-07        None        None         2        4     2019-12-09      2019-12-13
3   2019-12-06  2019-12-07  2019-12-09         2        1           None            None
4   2020-12-09        None        None         3        2     2019-12-12      2019-12-14
```

The logic here is quite simple, I want add up m2 + m2_m3 to have m3_estimated

Comment: How do you get m2_estimated? For ID=1, why m3_estimated is not None if m2 is None?

Comment: m2_estimated is calculated by adding up m1+m1_m2; 
why m3_estimated is not None if m2 is None? i want to have m3_estimated for each row with m3 = None

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the logic. 
Say, ID=0: m1 + m1_m2 = '2019-12-07', but you expect None (?)
ID=1: m2 + m2_m3 = None, but you expect '2019-12-10' (?)

Comment: Sorry it's me , i made some mistakes in the dataframe that i've edited.
If m2 is None the is use the estimated m2 to get m3 estimated. Is that clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['m2_estimated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['m1']) + df['m1_m2']
```

The code above is sufficient. You have to make sure that m1_m2 is on a integer format.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['m2_estimated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['m1']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['m1_m2'], unit='D')
```

You can turn it to date, if you don't want datetime using *dt* accessor:

```
df['m2_estimated'] = df['m2_estimated'].dt.date
```